# mysql query to count customers with certain number of products

Tags: mysql, count, nested

I have a customer table containing these two fields (actually way more but this is simplified):  customerAcct, product
I need to count the number of customers that have a certain number of each product.  Results would look like this:

```
Accounts  Product  Quantity
   100    ProductA    3
    40    ProductA    2
    20    ProductA    1
    80    ProductB    3
    60    ProductB    2
    30    ProductB    1
```

and so on.  So basically it's telling me that 100 customers have 3 of ProductA, 40 customers have 2 of ProductA, and 20 customers have 1 of ProductA.  Then same for ProductB.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the table schemas for your 2 tables `show create table  customerAcct` and `show create table  product`

Comment: I don't have two tables, just the one.  I clarified the question.

Comment: Ok, add the schema for that table.

Comment: Oh, I get it you have a table with 2 fields.

Comment: That table doesn't actually exist ... the real table has many fields and would be too much information in a question.  I can create a simple table if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Accounts, product, cnt AS Quantity
FROM (
  SELECT customerAcct, product, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM Customer
  GROUP BY customerAcct, product) AS t
GROUP BY product, cnt
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2005/2)